# jquery appended element from xml and SEO

Tags: jquery, xml, seo, append

I have created a website based on an xml database file.
This is a one page website that displays a portfolio, blog and articles contents.

My index.html page uses jquery isotope plugin to display thumbnails.
All this thumbnails are appended onload from my xml file.
When a thumbnail is clicked, new content are appended, url change thanks to history.js and displayed from my xml file.

So near all my content is append from xml and are not hardcoded.
Everything works fine and it is very fast.
(My xml database is not very huge... it will have 100-200 entries at maximum (like a personal blog or portfolio). For each entry, there is an url, some image link, a title, tags, and descriptions).

Here an example of an entry :

```
<element id="10" size="wide" category="portfolio">
    <tag tag="tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4"></tag>
    <icon class="icon-picture"></icon>
    <urlpage url="/portfolio/url.html"></urlpage>
    <urlimage src='./Post thumbnail images/image.jpg'></urlimage>
    <date date="05 Feb"></date>
    <title>title</title>
    <Description>blablablabla 50 lines maximum...</Description>
</element>
```

However, I'm asking an important question about SEO....
How can I optimize my website with SEO.

Does a sitemap will works and be enough?

If I chose xml database, it's because my entries are not very complicated. And I have created a live admin panel that allows to remove, edit or create new entries to xml file.

By the way I started to learn webcoding 4 months ago... So ,I'm new in this world...

Sorry for my English, I'm French.

Answer (score 0):

A sitemap is not sufficient in terms of SEO.
When a crawler gets your page, it doesn't use JavaScript, so it will appear as if it's empty (that is if you load all the content with JavaScript).

If you really want good SEO, you should make sure that the content is available in the HTML. If you still want to read from the XML-file you should use a server-side technology such as PHP, JSP, ASP.NET, ...

If you still want the same user experience as with the JS solution, you could employ a technique where you only serve it directly if it's a google crawler, but not if it's a normal user. (or even better, serve it directly if the client doesn't have JS enabled).

This is a small overview of the techniques you would need to do this. It's not possible to explain all these things in an SO-answer. However, you could read up a bit on these techniques, try some things out and come back here if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And if I create a fake index page with all element hardcoded. This fake page will not use for client but only for SEO. Is it possible? How does flash websites do for SEO? It seems to be the same problem but they are correctly referenced in search engine...